# Java threads, green or native?

Tags: java, multithreading

are Java Threads running on different processors core if I have multi-cores machine? In other words, if I run Thread.start(), is this thread green or native?

Thanks

Comment: Native, that is multi-core helps.

Comment: This depends on your Java implementation (and platform) iirc. It's easy to test though...

Answer (score 4):

> In Java 1.1, green threads were the only threading model used by the JVM, at least on Solaris. As green threads have some limitations compared to native threads, subsequent Java versions dropped them in favor of native threads.
>
> An exception to this is the Squawk virtual machine, which is a mixture between an operating system for low-power devices and a Java virtual machine. It uses green threads in order to keep the native code to an absolute minimum and to support the migration of its isolates.

So says [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).