# Parallel stream java Sumarization

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Java parallel streams will always perform every operation in parallel and return the same result?

E.g.

```
    IntStream of = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3);
    of = of.parallel();

    int reduce = of.reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println("Result: " + reduce);
```

Will this always return 6?

Comment: It will, but still, just calling `sum()` on the `IntStream` is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to give an answer on all your questions:

1. Regarding your example: `of.reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b);`

   - Will this *always* return the same result? (...always return 6?) => yes
   - Will this *always* perform in parallel? => no
2. Regarding all operations on Java Streams

   - Will they *always* return the same result? => no
   - Will they *always* perform in parallel? => no

## # 1.Quick answer #

### 1.1 Regarding your example: `of.reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + b);`

**1.1.1 Will this always return the same result?**

Yes, it will always yield the same result, no matter how often you will run the program. Provided your implementation of the JVM and your computer (hardware and OS) are working correctly.

Java just [asks you to use an associative operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) (you provided `(+)`) and the identity of the set of integers (you provided `0`). More Information in the *Background* section.

**1.1.2 Will this always perform in parallel?**

If you mean by *parallel* truly parallel (different computations are done at the same time), then this part of the question can be answered by a clear *no*.

1. If, e.g. you only have one thread at hand, your hardware is just not capable of performing truly parallel computations.
2. It is possible, that the JVM on your operating system is only supporting *user-level-threads*. This is a very portable method of implementing the behavior of multithreading eventhough it is no true multithreading. Meaning If your JVM only uses such "green threads" then even though  you have multiple CPUs, those threads cannot be executed in parallel, because your Kernel does not know of any additional threads. Some additional wiki info on that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads). But as wiki also states, the implementation of green-threads is not common in newer implementations of the JVM - Only Squawk Virtual Machine seems to be a recent exception, as of  [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258474/java-threads-green-or-native).
3. Another thing is, maybe multiple threads for the calculation of three integers are too much of an overhead. So the JVM might just say:

   "Well, he wants me do calculate THIS in parallel?! Really?!... No I will just calculate that sequencially because it would be too expensive to create extra threads for this kind of small calculation!"

If, on the other hand, you **do** have the necessary hardware, and the calculations are difficult enough for the JVM to not optimize multithreading away, then yes it will always be computed in parallel.

### 1.2 Regarding all operations on Java Streams

**1.2.1 Will they always return the same result?**

No, this depends on the operation and datastructures you use. There can be problems of side-effects, stateful expressions and ordering.

See *section 2.3.2: Other operations on parallel streams* in this answer for more information.

**1.2.2 Will they always perform in parallel?**

No, here again the points are valid that are written in the section *Regarding your example: Will this always perform in parallel*.

Additionally you could implement or use other datastructures and define your own collection operations and so on so:

If you are using datastructures that are too much synchronized, your calculations might actually be done sequentially, eventhough you are using multiple threads. That is when one thread blocks all other threads from further calculations until itself is done.

## # 2 Background #

The *Intro* and *Example for the general case* will introduce the functionality of reduction and why it can successfully yield the same result in every case.

*Java in specific* adds some information that holds true for the implementation of reduction that is specific in Java. In the end there is also information about other operations than reduce.

### 2.1 Intro

I would suggest that it will depend on the function you use and the context (set of objects) you apply this function to.

In your case you use the function (+) with integers (1,2,3).

(+) has some rules in the set of integers:

- a + b = b + a
- a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c

So in a general case, those rules (and some others) make it possible for the reduction to **always** under every circumstance generate the same result, independently of the (correct) implementation of the reduction.

### 2.2 Example for the general case

You have got the function (+) and an ordered sequence: (1,2,3).

Let's say there are 3 Threads:

- The collector-thread distributes: (1,3) to Thread 1, (2,0) to Thread 2.
- Thread 1 calculates: `1 + 3` and returns `4` to the collector-thread.
- Thread 2 calculates: `2 + 0` and returns `2` to the collector-thread.
- The collector-thread calculates: `4 + 2 = 6` and returns it as the result.

In this general example the collector is acting **unordered** which means, he does not care about the order of the elements in the sequence and distributes the calculations randomly and also just merges the results by the order in which they are finished by the Subthreads.

In which order those calculations are done by the threads will not make any difference as of the rules that can be applied for the function (+) in the set of integers.

### 2.3 Java in specific

**2.3.1 someStream.reduce(identity, someOrderedSequence)**

As Holger stated in the comments, the commutative property is not necessary.

Contrary to my *Example for the general case** the collector for this operation in Java is **ordered**. So it indeed **cares** about the order of the provided sequence. It will distribute the ranges in order and also collect the results in the correct order.

Because that is the case, Java's `IntStream` class has less restrictions on the properties of the set of objects and the function:

The function just has to have the *associative property*, meaning for (+): `a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c`.

So in the end the explicitness of the result is only dependent of the associative property, because Java's reduction is implemented to use the elements of the stream and the results of the calculations *in order*.

From the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

> int   reduce(int identity, IntBinaryOperator op)
>
> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity value and
>   an associative accumulation function, and returns the reduced value.

**2.3.2 Other operations on parallel streams**

**Intro**

Putting aside the specific `reduce(...)` function, your question also included a query about the general case:

> Java parallel streams will always (...) every operation (...) return the same result?

This part of the question can be replied with "no", because it depends on the operation and the datastructure you perform your operation on.

There are good general [descriptions on using Streams in the Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).

**Statefulness**

The Java documentation itself provides [an example of a stateful lambda expression on parallel streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

```
 Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
 stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })...
```

> Here, if the mapping operation is performed in parallel, the results
>   for the same input could vary from run to run, due to thread
>   scheduling differences.

**Side-effects**

> As an example of how to transform a stream pipeline that
>   inappropriately uses side-effects to one that does not, the following
>   code searches a stream of strings for those matching a given regular
>   expression, and puts the matches in a list.

```
 ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
 stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
       .forEach(s -> results.add(s));  // Unnecessary use of side-effects!
```

> This code unnecessarily uses side-effects. If executed in parallel,
>   the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would cause incorrect results,...

**Ordering**

I already talked about ordering when I wrote about Java's specific implementation, that only needs an associative operation to always return the same result.

Order does matter! Your provided example works on an ordered sequence of Integers and uses an ordered collector and thus always creates the same result. Whether or not it is actually performing the task in parallel under the hood.

If, on the other hand, you would use an unordered Stream and/or an unordered Collector those promises won't hold true anymore. See this quote [from the Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering):

> If a stream is ordered, most operations are constrained to operate on
>   the elements in their encounter order; if the source of a stream is a
>   List containing [1, 2, 3], then the result of executing map(x -> x*2)
>   must be [2, 4, 6]. However, if the source has no defined encounter
>   order, then any permutation of the values [2, 4, 6] would be a valid
>   result.

So then again you could regard *The example on the general case*. Here it's pointed out, that even if the sequence and the collector is unordered, the result must still be the same every time because `(+)` also has the commutative property in the set of integers.

## # 3 Conclusion #

All in all whether or not Java is really doing a truly parallel execution on Streams and always returns the same result depends on a lot of factors. So there cannot be a (yes/no) answer in general.

If you would have a set of assumptions you would apply as a precondition to your questions, then the answers could be more straight forward (e.g. specific hardware capabilities, JVM that always performs true parallelism, datastructures that are always in order, ...).

Comment: The rule `a + b = b + a` is not even needed for this to work. That’s why `reduce("", String::concat)` works as well, as only `a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c` is required.

Comment: Yes it is needed, isn't it?:

If `a + b != b + a`, then it would depend on the collector if it would take the result from thread 1 as the first or second operand of the final calculation.

Comment: Unless, of course java itself is making promises of how they handle the data in a stream.

Comment: That’s provided by the specification. A function for which `a ∘ b == b ∘ a` is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). A function for which `(a ∘ b) ∘ c = a ∘ (b ∘ c)` is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). And [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) says “*The `accumulator` function must be an [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) function.*”

Comment: Yes, I included that already into my answer when I read it in the specs.

Comment: As an addition, the current implementation of the Stream API will not fall back to sequential execution for tasks that are too simple. For most real life scenarios that would be unpredictable anyway. So the behavior is, “if you request parallel, you get parallel, regardless of whether there is a benefit”. But, of course, submitting three tasks to different threads for the operation of the question still doesn’t guaranty true parallelism, especially when the actual job takes less time than submitting and picking up a job. So you can have the “parallel execution mode” without parallel execution…

Comment: …and in the specific example of the question, there can’t be true parallelism, as the entire job consists of two additions only, one needing the result of the other as input, so turning on parallel execution allows to calculate `1+(2+3)` instead of `(1+2)+3`, but this would still perform one addition after the other. So here, you would need at least four stream elements to have actual parallel execution. Or you insert a `map` or `filter` operation before the reduction.

Comment: @Holger what I don't understand is that even if the common pool has a forced setting of zero threads (meaning it's just one) the `trySplit` is still called; would that make a good case for still sequential execution?

Comment: @Eugene: the standard strategy is to split to more part than threads/cores to be able to compensate for different execution times. This has no benefit in the special case of no actual parallelism, but there is no sense in spending development resources to optimize a corner case.

Comment: @Holger thank you... I was sort of inclined to think it like this too, but was not sure. much appreciated.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the comments, do you have any resources on the “...request (...) parallel, get parallel, regardless of (...) benefit”. I mean something like "The JVM MUST always create parallelism when user asked - All future impl of the JVM must create this behavior" ? I thought the JVM could do pretty much do anything for better execution time and not give to much promises on how one JVM impl acts the same (under the hood) than other ones. Even optimize on different execution stages for a specific program. In the end, at the top abstractionlayer we only have java virtual threads.

Comment: @Jan: there is indeed no guaranty for parallel execution, but while falling back to sequential execution for simple tasks would be a nice-to-have, that’s simply not happening today and would require substantial effort at different places in the implementation. Therefore, programmers today have to deal with this by not requesting parallel execution, unless the workload really deserves it.

Answer (score 2):

parallel or sequential will not influence the ultimate result, if you have not violated some rule that is... For example if you write:

```
int reduce = of.reduce(10, (a,b) -> a + b); // notice the 10 instead of zero
```

the result depends on parallel/sequential invocations (and also on the number of CPU that you have). This happens because you violate the `identity rule`...

Otherwise running an operation in parallel will yield the same result as sequential execution.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `6` because `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`.

It doesn't matter whether the summation is performed as `1 + (2 + 3)` or `(1 + 2) + 3`, or just `1 + 2 + 3`, either sequentially or in parallel.

`Stream.reduce(identity, operator)` expects the identity and an *associative* binary operator. As your operator is the `+` operator, then `0` is the identity for this operator. As long as you don't violate the contract of the `Stream.reduce` method (and you haven't done it in your question), the result will always be correct, no matter the underlying implementation and algorithms being used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which operation are you talking about. `reduce` will always yield same results as long as you provide it with an associative merge function.

But, for example, there is no guarantee that `findAny` will always return same element, hence the name.